# How to set SageMaker xgboost's eval_metric to f1?

Tags: xgboost, amazon-sagemaker, xgbclassifier

I tried SageMaker's AutoPilot to solve a binary classification problem and I found it is using f1 as the evaluation metric. But when I tried to write some code without tuning like this:

```py
xgb.set_hyperparameters(max_depth=5,
                        eta=0.2,
                        gamma=4,
                        min_child_weight=6,
                        subsample=0.8,
                        objective='binary:logistic',
                        eval_metric='f1',
                        num_round=100)
```

This generates the following error:

> [2021-10-17:00:02:19:ERROR] Customer Error: Metric 'f1' is not
> supported. Parameter 'eval_metric' should be one of these
> options:'rmse', 'mae', 'logloss', 'error', 'merror', 'mlogloss',
> 'auc', 'ndcg', 'map', 'poisson-nloglik', 'gamma-nloglik',
> 'gamma-deviance', 'tweedie-nloglik'.

Since the autopilot was able to compute F1, I feel like it is supported in the hyperparameter setting in some fashion? Am I misunderstanding?

Any help is going to be appreciated.

Comment: use validation:f1 with a validation channel. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost-tuning.html

Comment: Thanks. I actually read the same article and tried eval_metric="validation:f1" but I got the same error. When you say "a validation channel", what does that mean?

Comment: I believe you can set eval_metric="error" in a single training job, but can set validation:f1 
in a hyperparameter tuning job

Answer (score 0):

You can define the metrics that you want to send to CloudWatch by specifying a list of metric names and regular expressions as the metric_definitions argument when you initialize an Estimator object. See it here: [Documentation](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-sagemaker-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/training-metrics.md)

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.estimator import Estimator

estimator = Estimator(
    image_uri="your-own-image-uri",
    role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(), 
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker.Session(),
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
    metric_definitions=[
       {'Name': 'train:error', 'Regex': 'Train_error=(.*?);'},
       {'Name': 'validation:error', 'Regex': 'Valid_error=(.*?);'}
    ]
)
```